# Spring Security - Multiple Entities for One IDP

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

I am looking to have multiple entity IDs point to the same IDP. Looks like I can do this with an entity alias but adding that to the extended metadata didn't make any changes.

Answer (score 0):

For the alias approach, you may want to add more details on how you have configured your extended metadata and the behavior you are experiencing.

Also, assuming you have SP initiated flow, there is another way to have multiple SP(identical) point to the same IDP while holding identical SP metadata xml. This would involve you to provide configure a parameter assertionConsumerIndex in your bean configuration for MetadataGeneratorFilter. See below:

```
<bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
<constructor-arg>
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
        <property name="entityId" value="<YOUR-ENTITY-ID-SAME-ON-ALL-SP>"/>
        <property name="assertionConsumerIndex" value="<INT-VALUE-DIFF-ON-EACH-SP>" /> <!-- value e.g. 1, 2, 3 etc -->
```

Then on the IDP, these indexes will correspond to particular endpoint urls within the same IDP instance. Not sure if this fits your scenario but wanted to make you aware of another option. You should be able to find more information by searching for "assertionConsumerIndex" in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/)